# Remove tint on TableView iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to remove the white view behind the alphabet indexer but have had no luck.
I am trying to make it clear but nothing has worked for me so far.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA, therefore you might not get any response to your question.

Comment: iOS 6.0 introduced a "sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor" property. Might be relevant here as well.

Comment: @rckoenes hasnt that been removed since GM was released?

Comment: @MahmoudA No, it is even state in the yellow notification above the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sectionIndexBackgroundColor` is what your looking for. You can do something like this,

```
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you want to change the color of the highlighted state, use the following property.

```
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Keep in mind that `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` became available in iOS7. So if your supporting iOS6 you might want to call something like this.

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(sectionIndexBackgroundColor)]) {
    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```